# Reference request: Deligne's conjecture (cycles)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-cycles

In "The work of Tate" Milne says:

> "The relation between the two conjectures has been greatly clarified by the work
>   of Deligne. He defines the notion of an absolute Hodge class on a (complete smooth)
>   variety over a field of characteristic zero, and conjectures that every Hodge class on
>   a variety over C is absolutely Hodge. The Tate conjecture for a variety implies that
>   all absolute Hodge classes on the variety are algebraic. Therefore, in the presence of
>   Deligne’s conjecture, the Tate conjecture implies the Hodge conjecture. As Deligne
>   has proved his conjecture for abelian varieties, this gives another proof of Piatetski-
>   Shapiro’s theorem."

In which work (articles) Deligne shows this conjecture?

Is there some book (or expository article) about this conjecture and its connections with Tate and Hodge conjectures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deligne, *Hodge Cycles on Abelian Varieties*, in Hodge Cycles, Motives, and Shimura Varieties,
Lecture Notes in Math. 900, 1981, pp. 9-100. Maybe you could use Google to find these references by yourself?